# How to get the values of a multi-dimensional array by key in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Let's say for example you have a constant multi-dimensional array with multiple keys (and values), but you want to filter out specific keys with it's values. See a example array below:

```
const defaultInvestmentFields = [
     [
         'type' => 'system',
         'investment_name' => 'Ballast'
     ],
     [
         'type' => 'system',
         'investment_name' => 'Inverters'
     ],
        [
         'type' => 'system',
         'investment_name' => 'Extra garantie inverters'
     ]
];
```

The output I want is an array with only the values of investment_name. Like `['Ballast', 'Inverters', 'Extra garantie inverters']`.

Comment: `array_column` is function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to [@Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12564060/levi-roelofsma)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68663657/7451109), you can use an [array helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#arrays-and-objects-method-list) to avoid having to transform the array into a collection and back: [`Arr::pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-pluck)

```php
Arr::pluck(Project::defaultInvestmentFields, 'investment_name');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's way faster, but transforming it to a collection will give more flexibility.

Comment: You're welcome. Sure, flexibility where flexibility is due.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and neat solution would be to use the `collect` wrapper function which is provided by Laravel. After that we can use the `pluck` function in order to specify which values by their key(s) we want to get. For example:

```
collect(Project::defaultInvestmentFields)->pluck('investment_name');
```

Now we have a Collection of the following values: Ballast, Inverters and Extra garantie inverters.
In order to use it as an array, simply call `toArray()` on it.